# LAMP stack with apache and php on one linux server and mysql on a different linux server

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, mysql, php, lamp

I am pretty new to linux and LAMP setup. I want to setup a LAMP environment with AP on one linux server and M on a different linux server. I have a hard time finding a relevant document with such a configuration.

I have done the following steps so far:

server1:

```
yum install -y httpd
/sbin/service httpd restart
yum install -y php php-mysql
sed -i "s/Listen 80/#Listen 80/g" /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
yum install -y mod_ssl openssl
/sbin/service httpd restart
service iptables stop
```

I changed the ServerName in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf from

```
#ServerName www.example.com:80
```

to

```
ServerName 172.32.35.14 (ip address of server1)
/sbin/service httpd restart
```

server2:

```
yum install -y mysql-libs
yum install -y mysql
yum install -y perl-DBI
yum install -y perl-DBD-MySQL
yum install -y mysql-server
/sbin/chkconfig mysqld on
/sbin/service mysqld start
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE USER 'mysqluser' IDENTIFIED by 'password'" 
mysql -u root  -e "CREATE USER 'mysqluser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED by 'password'"
mysql -u root  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql -u root  -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'mysqluser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"
mysql -u mysqluser -p password -e "CREATE DATABASE mysqldb" 
mysql -u mysqluser -p password mysqldb < /tmp/mysqlinstaller/world.sql
service iptables stop
```

Then I had these post configuration steps:

On server 2, where my mysql is installed, I did the following:

```
bind-address = 172.32.35.14 (ip of server 1 where apache/php are installed)
service mysql restart
```

But I am not able to establish a connection. Can you point out what I am missing and guide me please.

Comment: try if you can reach Mysql posrt using `nc IPserver2 3306 &> /dev/null; echo $?` on server 1 to try if you can access to server 2 Mysql port (3306 is default port, change value if you changed Mysql port). Result should be 1 if ok else it will output 0

Comment: I got the response as 127

Comment: I see the following error when I restart mysqld - 

    service mysqld restart
    Stopping mysqld:                                           [  OK  ]
    MySQL Daemon failed to start.
    Starting mysqld:                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Check your mysql logs to know why (for the command `nc IPserver2 3306` would be enought to get info if Mysql is reachable)

Comment: I even couldnt reach my apache server... I tried http://172.17.50.23/... it just says Problem loading page... Seems like I missed something

Answer (score 2):

You tried to bind MySQL to the wrong address.

```
bind-address = 172.32.35.14
```

This address specifies what IP address *on that server* which MySQL *listens* to and receives connections.

It should either remain unset, to listen on all interfaces, or set to the IP address of the server it's running on.

Comment: I did bind my MySQL server ip address and the mysqld service has started successfully. Thanks. But still I am not able to access the apache server via http://172.17.50.23.

Comment: And one basic question.. sorry for that... but my MySQL is remote. How will my apache server know to communicate with MySQL if I dont provide an IP

Comment: Apache does not communicate with your database server. Your application does. So you need to configure your application accordingly.

Comment: oh ok. Got it. Can you please help me with the access to my apache/php server via url

Comment: enabled the port 80 and gave the ServerName 172.32.35.14. I have a sample info.php with the following code <?php phpinfo(); ?> inside. Changed the permissions to 777 and tried to access 172.32.35.14/info.php. But in vain. Problem loading page :(